# How to link to a post in chat, to be accessed outside chat?

Tags: support, chat, hyperlinks

In chat, there is an option to `link my next chat message as a reply to this`. But I do not see a way to get a hyperlink to the chat transcript, at a particular post.

I know this is possible (that is, that it is possible to formulate such a link), because links like this appear in my StackExchange inbox when someone replies and pings me (with @EliahKagan) in chat.

How can I get a link like this for any post (not just posts I've been notified about in my SE inbox)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Click on the grey down arrow on the post and then copy the permalink on the pop up box.

Comment: Now I feel I should have been able to figure this out... Oh well--thanks for the answer!

Comment: @EliahKagan worry not, we all have our _doh!_ moments ;)

Comment: If only I could downvote my own post... ;-)